# Geo-location based iOS push notification. (eg. urban airship)

Tags: iphone, push-notification, geolocation, ios11, urbanairship.com

I want to restrict the push notification based on location, means I want to send different notification for different cities.

Is it possible from Urban airship SDK? Is there any other way possible to send geo-location based push notification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution.
We can enable location by adding these 2 lines in code,

`UAirship.location().isBackgroundLocationUpdatesAllowed = true`
`UAirship.location().isLocationUpdatesEnabled = true`

and we can filter all users from urban airship account, according to location.